# JAVA_HOME variable shows a blank line on the terminal

Tags: java, environment-variables, bashrc

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. I'm logged in to Ubuntu as `user1`. I installed Oracle JDK version `jdk1.8.0_144` to `/usr/local/java` and set symlinks as

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/java" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/javaws" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/java
$ sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac
$ sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/javaws
```

Then, I opened `.bashrc` file with `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`  and added the following lines to the end of the file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

and saved by typing Ctrl+O.

However, when I type `echo $JAVA_HOME`, terminal shows a blank line. I closed and opened the `.bashrc` file and the two lines are still there, so I did save the file properly I think.

Comment: Open a new terminal

Comment: Oh oops, it works... Sorry for the trouble.  Do you want to add it as the answer so I can accept?

Comment: Remove this braces into your commands. It will work if you type `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`. Put these lines in `./~profile`

Comment: @Redbob the braces are fine, the file is called `~/.profile` and anyway, that would make no difference. While `~/.profile` is indeed the preferred place to put such global variables, `~/.bashrc` will also work fine and, more importantly, there is no guarantee that `~/.profile` will be read when logging in graphically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~/.bashrc` file is read *once* every time a new interactive non-login shell is started. In other words, every time you open a new terminal or just run `bash` in an already opened terminal. So any changes you have made there won't take effect until you open a new terminal to start a new bash session.

Alternatively, you can `source` the file in your current session with:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

That said, *never open files with `sudo` unless necessary* and it is never necessary for `~/.bashrc`. Make sure the file still belongs to your user (`ls -l ~/.bashrc`), change ownership if needed (`chown swdon:swdon ~/.bashrc`) and get into the habit of *never* using `sudo` unless you know it is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I'm trying to run an application server that uses JDK  through `JAVA_HOME`. However, the application is saying `JAVA_HOME is not correctly set`. Do you have any idea? I installed the application in `/opt` so I run using `sudo wso2server.sh`.

Comment: @swdon why do you run using `sudo`? Are you sure that's needed? If you are 100% sure you need `sudo` (which seems like a horribly bad idea, why would you need to run a java program as root?), try `sudo -E wso2server.sh`. But first try just `wso2server.sh`.

Comment: When I try to run it without `sudo` I get `Permission Denied` error. I think it's because the java app is in `/opt` directory? You are a genius! It worked with `-E` switch. I will ask this in a separate question. Could you help answer with a bit more detail? :)